# Where can I read about Valleytronics?

Tags: band-structure, condensed-matter, spin-orbit-coupling, graphene, valleytronics

Where can I read about [Valleytronics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valleytronics)? Are there any good books or review papers or influential papers on this topic?

The question was also posted at the [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/790684/49107) site.

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! Thank you for contributing your question here, and we hope to see much more of you in the future! One place would start would be our [tag:valleytronics] tag, including our question [Tools for Valleytronic Research](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/907/5) which was asked within 1 month of this website going live.